# Python storing value of old assigned variable

Tags: logic

lets say i have this code

```
x = 5

while True:
    x = 10
break
```

is there a way I can keep the original value of x and the new assigned value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern might be what you're looking for

```
x = 5
y = 0
while True:
    # y stores old value of x
    y = x
    x = 10

# example where x actually changes
while True:
    y = x
    x += 1
    print(y, x)
```